# How I can using SocketIO in existing ReactJS project without Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have an existing ReactJS project and now I wanna use SocketIO and I don't want to use Express. How I can do?

My project struture:

- public

  - index.html
- src

  - components
  - app.js
  - index.js

I use *.jsx file for components. I have tried [text](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react) and [text](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-installation/) but it isn't work. I don't understand how it work.

Thanks all.